# Modal Form Connected to SQLite3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have the following code that is purposed to display a table of data and allow the user to add a new row by clicking a +New button, which opens a modal with the correct form, and then the user hits submit and the new row saves in the table.

I am struggling to convert the modal from static, fake data to the data coming from my SQLite3 database. Anytime I try and add my fields (e.g. { stakeholder.employee }) into the modal I get an error:

Error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 123: 'stakeholder.id'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Table of existing data with a button on top to add a new row:

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary badge-pill float-right" style="font-size: 14px; width:80px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">+ New</button>
        </div>

   <table class="table table-hover" style="width:90% ">
      <thead>
        <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Employee</th>
          <th scope="col">Stakeholder Group</th>
          <th scope="col">Quadrant</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for stakeholder in stakeholder_list %}
        <tr style="font-family: Graphik;font-size: 12px">
          <td>{{ stakeholder.id }}</td>
          <td style="font-size: 15px">{{ stakeholder.employee }}</li></td>
          <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_group }}</td>
          <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_quadrant }}</td>
          <td>{{ stakeholder.description }}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And a Modal that I am trying to convert into a form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Customer Form</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  
            {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <form>
          {% for field in form %}
          {% endfor %}

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Doe, John">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text" style="color:red"><i>*Required Field</i></small>
          </div>  
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

models.py

```
class Stakeholder(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_group = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_quadrant = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stakeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

The error being raised:

```
Invalid block tag on line 123: 'stakeholder.id'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

In my experience can be raised in cases such as the following:

1. An unclosed tag within the document
2. Malformed mustache variable `{% stakeholder.id %}` maybe?
3. Entangled tags?

So I recommend you sift through your template for such cases. My bet is thats where your problem is coming from.